# TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'content'

Tags: elasticsearch, haystack

I am using Haystack for searching query when i write documents in document store, Unfortunately This error occurred for me.
Here is my code:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    document_store = ElasticsearchDocumentStore(
        host='localhost',
        username='', password='',
        index='aurelius'
    )
    df = pd.read_csv('news.csv')
    print(df.columns)
    data_json = [{
        'text': text,
        'meta': {
            'source': 'news'
        }
    } for text in df['Text'].values]
    document_store.write_documents(data_json)
    retriever_elastic = DensePassageRetriever(
        document_store=document_store,
        query_embedding_model='facebook/dpr-question_encoder-single-nq-base',
        passage_embedding_model='facebook/dpr-ctx_encoder-single-nq-base',
        embed_title=True
    )
    document_store.update_embeddings(retriever=retriever_elastic)
    print(retriever_elastic.retrieve("german business confidence slides german business confidence fell in february knocking hopes of a speedy recovery in europe s largest economy. "))
```

Comment: the JSON format in latest Haystack has to be `content` instead of `text` So it should be `{"content": "<the-actual-text>"}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on @UninformedUser reply.

I assume that it is the `document.store.write_documents(data_json)` that throws the exception. As the format for the argument has been changed from `{ 'text': str, 'meta': obj}` to `{'content': str, 'meta': obj}`.

So basically you only need to fix the list comprehension part of your code:

```py
data_json = [{
    'content': text,
    'meta': {
        'source': 'news'
    }
} for text in df['Text'].values]
document_store.write_documents(data_json)
```

Comment: Thanks this worked for elasticsearch 8.2.3 and farm-haystack 1.5.0